# CSS Helvetica Neue not working

Tags: css, font-face

I am trying to use Helvetica Neue as the font for my website everywhere so I applied to the body like so

```
body {
    background-image: url("http://inauguralseason.com/wp-content/themes/twentyeleven/images/background.jpg");
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue" !important;
}
```

but my font does not appear, it was working at one point but now its not working in Firefox, Chrome, Safari or IE

you can see what I am talking about here

http://inauguralseason.com/

any help would be appreciated,

Thanks,
J

Comment: That technique uses fonts installed on the users' OS. You better link to a font in your site, not all work.

Comment: Are you trying to use the medium or normal version?

Comment: I am seeing the correct font on my end. But, as @jackJoe said, you should link to the font (see font-face in CSS3) and provide fallback fonts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to upload the font to your web-site and declare the font-face

```
@font-face
{
font-family: 'Helvetica Neue';
src: url('HelveticaNeue.ttf'),
     url('HelveticaNeue.eot'); /* IE9 */
}
```

and only then you can use it on your web-pages.

Comment: He already has @font-face included at the top of his CSS file it's a problem with the font-family name

Comment: Notice that not all fonts are available and allowed to be put in a site. Read the font conditions.

Comment: agree with @jackJoe some fonts have particular licenses

Answer (score 5):

Your @font-face seems to have the font family named as 'helvetica_neueregular' and I don't see a font set for your navigation but anywhere else if you add 'helvetica_neueregular' it loads the font. As far as browser consistency In Chrome dev tools it looks like you are missing some font browser types to provide full browser support.

http://inauguralseason.com/wp-content/themes/twentyeleven/style.css

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'helvetica_neueregular';
src: url('helveticaneue-medium-webfont.eot');
src: url('helveticaneue-medium-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
     url('helveticaneue-medium-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
     url('helveticaneue-medium-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
     url('helveticaneue-medium-webfont.svg#helvetica_neueregular') format('svg');
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;
}
```

EDIT: This is loading the medium font but it called regular just change to 'helvetica_neuemedium'